# Why is Bing indexing https links instead of http?

Tags: bing

Today I have used Microsoft's search engine Bing for the first time. Mainly to search for my own website and check the results. The weird problem is that Bing shows some of my site links with `https`. I have never used https or linked with it.

Example links (first position in search result):

- http://www.bing.com/search?q=wurzeln+einfach+g20
- http://www.bing.com/search?q=wurzeln+einfach+g05

As known, the `https` prevents the site from loading properly and displays a `There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.`

Two Questions:

1. What could be the reason that Bing is indexing https links instead of http?
2. How can I tell Bing to correct this?

Thanks.

PS: I have also canonical URLs specified that hold http URLs but obviously Bing is ignoring that.

Comment: Are you using a sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

`As known, the https prevents the site from loading properly and displays a There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.`

The issue is you self signed the certificate. You can validate it here: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.echteinfach.tv

You need to use a cert from a recognized authority or remove HTTPS

I suggest http://www.startssl.com/ as it's free!